# How can I change the split ruler in Macvim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to change the split ruler of as shown in screen-shot. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate ?

[image: MACVIM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `fillchars`. Use like this:

```
set fillchars=vert:║,fold:-
```

You can manually set the highlight using `VertSplit` (`:h hl-VertSplit`).

```
highlight VertSplit ctermfg=144
```